# Why does trying to break 2 for loops by setting the counters to the condition result in an error

Tags: java

So I noticed that running this code will result in a `IndexOutOfBounds` error. So I have a condition where I need to `break` if the condition is true but breaking by setting the counters doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and what should I be doing to break out of the 2 `for` loops?

The method `getRequirements()` just simply returns an 2D array of [7][24].

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.getRequirements().length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.getRequirements()[i].length; j++) {
            if (j == 3) {
                j = s.getRequirements()[i].length;
                i = s.getRequirements().length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
j = s.getRequirements()[i].length;
i = s.getRequirements().length;
```

^ it's guaranteed to trigger `IndexOutOfBounds` because you assigning `i` variable in inner loop (og `j`) which does not check for `i` as it terminal condition.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting "i" again in the line 5?

If you want to break the parent for loop, just label it `outer:` and use `break outer;`.
If you don't do it, the "i" gets updated with the length of requirements, but the "j" loop will still process, thus causing the error on the next get using i.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this results in an error is that the loops are broken out of in order from innermost to outermost, so the condition `j < s.getRequirements()[i].length` is checked with an out of bounds value of `i` rather than being skipped due to not passing the outer loop's bounds check.

In general, the best way to break out of multiple nested loops is usually a [labeled break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). In your code, that would look like this:

```
outerLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < s.getRequirements().length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s.getRequirements()[i].length; j++) {
        if (j == 3) {
            break outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the loop index variables is needed only if code after the loops cares about them.

Answer (score 0):

The direct cause of this exception is that the inner loop condition depends on `i`, which is changed to beyond the final element on purpose.

```
j < s.getRequirements()[i].length
                        ^ length of the i-th requirement
```

After the assignment `i = s.getRequirements().length`, the code tries to evaluate the inner loop condition based on the new value of `i`, then you got your exception.

As suggested by @Douglas, you should use a labelled break to break more than two loops.

If you really want to do it, you can use a local variable to hold the sub array length:

```
int n = s.getRequirements()[i].length;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (...) {
         j = n;
         i = s.getRequirements().length;
    }
}
```